# Best way to load a custom UIView which is linked to a xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, swift, xib

I'm subclassing UIView (which will be a basic menu) and this custom view is linked to a xib file for 
its design.

The files are :

- CustomView.swift
- CustomView.xib

I'm working also with storyboard which has only one controller (the *initial* viewcontroller) which loads the CustomView this way (in its *viewDidLoad* method):

```
self.menuView = CustomView(frame: self.view.bounds)
self.view.addSubview(self.menuView!)
```

I'm overriding the init method of the CustomView class as such :

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame:frame)
    var view = UINib(nibName: "CustomView", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil).lastObject() as CustomeView
    self.frame = frame
    view.frame = frame
    self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
    view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
    self.addSubview(view)
}
```

This works well but the issue is that I have a CustomView inside another CustomView (with the `self.addSubview(view)`)

Is there a better way to do that ?

Thanks a lot for any comment !

Comment: Could you give more information? So you have two xib-files and load a view from one xib into a view of anther xib? What is the reason that you have two speparate xib files in the first place? It is common but the reason should be known to give a good adivce.

Comment: So I just have 1 xib and a custom UIView attached to the xib (via CustomClass), I have a storyboard and a viewcontroller into this storyboard. I'm loading the custom view programmatically in the initial viewcontroller (method viewDidLoad)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do using:

```
self.menuView  =  NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? CustomView
self.view.addSubview(menuView)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good approach.

do directly;

```
    self.menuView = UINib(nibName: "CustomView", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil).lastObject() as CustomeView
    //set frame & mask of self.manuView if required
    self.view.addSubview(self.menuView!)
```

BTW there is no need to set frame and mask from code if using xib.

Comment: That means that the owner will now be the viewController instead of the subclass of UIView ? It seems really strange that the "homemade" component cannot be instantiated like any other component (UIButton,...)...